# Combining actions on event handlers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a jQuery statement which hides a `div` element on it's click event.  I'd like the element to fade out regardless if it isn't clicked after 5 seconds.  Is there a simple way I can call the `fadeOut` function in the same expression or without the `click` event interfering with the animation?

```js
$(".fadeOutbox").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: You want to hide it on click, but hide anyway if he doesn't click? When to know then?

Comment: You need to schedule the timeout after whatever event that I'm assuming this is appearing, you haven't specified any of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this is inside another function that shows the box to begin with. This solution will hide the box after 5 seconds, or immediately upon clicking.

```
var $box = $('.fadeOutbox');
var fadeOut = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $box.fadeOut('slow');
};
var timeout = setTimeout(fadeOut, 5000);
$box.click(fadeOut);
```

Answer (score 4):

Most jQuery components are chain-able, your function as it stands returns a reference to the initial object.

You can achieve what you want simply by using:

```
$(".fadeOutbox").click(function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut('slow');
}).delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Basically reads as onclick, fade out otherwise fade out after 5 seconds.

Comment: Don't use delay function because the animation from click handler will not work: http://jsfiddle.net/KSEXY/1/

Comment: @Johnツ well spotted - updated and works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit to clarify:

```
var clear = setTimeout(function(){ $(".fadeOutbox").fadeOut('slow'); }, 5000);

$(".fadeOutbox").on('click', function(){
  clearTimeout(clear);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mGbHq/

Comment: Clarified. Either that was edited in after I saw it, or I missed it. Correct answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Use a timeout **not** inside of the click handler:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $(".fadeOutbox").fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000);
```

Your jQuery code becomes:

```
// set a timeout for 5 seconds
setTimeout(function () {
    $(".fadeOutbox").fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000);

// attach click handler
$(".fadeOutbox").on("click", function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSEXY/)

Comment: @MikelMax Use timeout solution, the `delay()` solution blocks your div  click animation.

Answer (score 2):

Save the fact that the user has clicked or not and test it in the timer

```
var isClicked = false;

setTimeout(function () {
   if(!isClicked)
      $(".fadeOutbox").fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000);

$(".fadeOutbox").click(function () {
 isClicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var wasClicked = false;
$(".fadeOutbox").click(function () { wasClicked = true; });

setTimeout(function () {
   if(wasClicked = false)
       $(".fadeOutbox").fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try holding a variable for the timeout and clear it every time the user clicks.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/VT8V2/1/)

```
// Timeout variable
var t;

$('.fadeOutBox').click(function()
{
    $box = $(this);
    $box.fadeIn("fast");

    // Reset the timeout
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $box.fadeOut("slow");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, none of the answers gives the simple solution: Use `setTimeout` and cancel the timeout on click:

```
$(".fadeOutbox").click(function () {
    // Cache the jQuery object
    var $this = $(this);

    // Do we already have a timer running?
    var timer = $this.data("timer");
    if (timer) {
        // Yes, cancel it
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $this.removeData("timer");
    }

    // (You may want an `else` here, it's not clear)

    // In five seconds, fade out
    $this.data("timer", setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeData("timer");
        $this.fadeOut('slow');
    }, 5000));
});
```

I'm not 100% sure that the above is triggering on the events you want, but the two pieces of relevant code are this, which schedules the timed action:

```
// In five seconds, fade out
$this.data("timer", setTimeout(function() {
    $this.removeData("timer");
    $this.fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000));
```

and this, which cancels it (for instance, on click):

```
var timer = $this.data("timer");
if (timer) {
    // Yes, cancel it
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $this.removeData("timer");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#div').delay(5000).fadeOut(400)
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VRYBk/3/)

Comment: @Mikel Max asks to hide if not clicked only